# String.Format variable in composite string format

Tags: c#, string, datetime, composite, string.format

I would like to put a variable into composite format in String.Format. Meaning

```
String str = String.Format("{0:[what should I put here]}", mydate, myFormat};
```

so that the result will depend on myFormat.

```
myFormat = "yyyy" => str = "2015"
myFormat = "hh:mm:ss" => str = "08:20:20"
```

I did not suceed with

```
String.Format("{0:{1}}", mydate, myFormat}
```

nor

```
String.Format("{0:{{1}}}", mydate, myFormat}
```

nor

```
String.Format("{0:\{1\}}", mydate, myFormat}
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your format string should be like:

```
string str = "{{0:{0}}}";
```

Then you can format like this:

```
string format = string.Format(str, "yyyy");
format = string.Format(format, DateTime.Now); // this will give 2015
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to format a date string, there sure is a much easier way then your approach:

```
string myformat = "yyyy";
string secondFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy";
DateTime.Now.ToString(myformat) //2015
DateTime.Now.ToString(secondFormat) //24.04.2015
```